# Json value is not getting passed to MVC controller from AJAX call

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have this AJAX call using which I am trying to call a Partial view in my project.

```
function ImportBundle() {
        var req = { "from": "bundle" };
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: "Client/ZWS/{lang}/ImportBundles",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(req),
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $(".viewdiv").html(data);
            },
            failuere: function () { alert("fail"); }
        });
    }
```

This is my controller for the project:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ImportBundles([FromUri] string from)
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/_ViewImportBundles.cshtml");
        }
```

However, when I am debugging the application, I am getting null.

Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting the data in a variable?  data: {someVar : JSON.stringify(req) }   Then that would be your controller variable name  ImportBundles(string someVar)

Comment: Like this: var req = { "from": "bundle" }; data: { myVar : JSON.stringify(req) } ?

Comment: Tried that too. Not working :(

Comment: Did you try using url: "Client/ZWS/{lang}/ImportBundles?from=bundle" ? In a GET request, you pass parameters as part of the query string.

Comment: Do you know if the controller even gets called? Put a break point in it. It's possible that the url is wrong.

Comment: I debugged. The controller is getting called. but the value is null.

Comment: let me try url: "Client/ZWS/{lang}/ImportBundles?from=bundle"

Comment: nope. not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked. Maybe this can help you in the right direction.

```
    function ImportBundle() {

        var req = { "from": "bundle" };

            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Client/ImportBundles",
                data: { theData: JSON.stringify(req) },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Worked");
                },
                failuere: function () { alert("fail"); }
        });

     }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ImportBundles(string theData)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

The variable theData contained the json. If you can make this work, you can then modify the code to your need a little bit at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ImportBundle() {
        var req = { "from": "bundle" };
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: "Client/ZWS/{lang}/ImportBundles",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: req,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $(".viewdiv").html(data);
            },
            failure: function () { alert("fail"); }
        });
    }
```

For url, you can use Url.Action helper method.

Comment: unfortunately, I can not. My url has {lang} which gets data in runtime. But, @Url.Action does not do that. Also, I tried data: req,. not working :(

Comment: With the code that you pasted, I suspect that ajax call may not even be hitting your MVC action. If you are able to get break point in that MVC action, then I would check any custom routing defined in the project.